# redundant nested repeat operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Has anybody gotten this ruby warning before? "warning: redundant nested repeat operator"

What does it mean?

I get it when I start Webrick

This is how my trace looks like:

```
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib/rack/mount/strexp.rb:4
1: warning: redundant nested repeat operator
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing
/route.rb:25: warning: redundant nested repeat operator
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-mount-0.6.13/lib/rack/mount/route.rb:46
```

I'm using Rails 3.0.5 and Ruby 1.9.2 p180

Comment: In future please 1) indent stack traces or code examples in your post and 2) show the code which is causing the error that you would like fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you have a regular expression with two repeat operators on a single atom. E.g.,

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > re = /\w**/
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80: 
    warning: redundant nested repeat operator: /\w**/
=> /\w**/
```

Given that the backtrace has what looks like routing libraries (I've not personally used the rack-mount gem), I'd guess one of your routes either has a redundant repeat operator in it, or is being reduced down to a regex which has one.

Answer (score 2):

@michael's response got me to find the real problem:

If you have the following in your routes.rb,

```
match "/foo(/bar(/something)))" => "controller#action"
```

You get the warning mentioned above. It exists to warn you that `/foo` works, so does `/foo/bar` and so does `/foo/bar/something`